# How to delete Macbook from Find My iPhone without erasing data?

Tags: icloud, find-my-iphone, find-my-mac

I have an iCloud account and there are my phone and a macbook which not belongs to me. I removed it from Apple ID and settings in iCloud, but it is still in Find my iPhone. I only able to erase this macbook. Is there a way to just deatache it from my account without erasing data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In *Find iPhone* you should be able to tap on the device you want to remove. That will take you to the screen where you see the `Erase` option.

At the top-right of that screen is the option to `Remove` that device (see my iPad screenshot below).

[image]

If the `Remove` option doesn't appear immediately, give it a few minutes to show up. After tapping `Remove` you'll get a confirmation dialog box. Once you tap *Agree* the device will be removed.